# Apply custom CSS (persistently) to a site I view regularly, from my laptop?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have to spend a lot of time on some unfortunately terrible real estate websites.  I am moderately proficient with CSS and can (in FireFox) 'Inspect Element' and make CSS changes to hide or shrink gaudy elements of a particular page.  But I want to apply this custom CSS to all pages for the particular domain, and keep it as a profile (or similar) in my browser so it will remember and apply the CSS the next day.  Is there any browser/extension that can do this for me, or is this crossing some functionality boundaries which make browsers ... browsers?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of extensions in Firefox that can do that for you for example:
[Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stylish/), [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/styl-us/), or my own [FireMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firemonkey/), etc